# Django template cycle for alternating rows - without loop

Tags: django, django-templates

Perhaps this is a non-question, but how do you make use of the Django `{% cycle %}` functionality, or something similar, when you're not in a loop? Specifically, I have an HTML table that I'm writing by hand, since it's not the sort of thing you need to do in a loop. I want the rows to alternate, like this:

```
   <tr class="{% cycle 'even' 'odd'%}"></tr>
   <tr class="{% cycle 'even' 'odd'%}"></tr>
   <tr class="{% cycle 'even' 'odd'%}"></tr>
```

But I'm not using  a loop, so this always results in `even`. I don't want a situation where I want to insert one row later, and then have to change the classes of all rows beneath it by hand. Am I just being petty? How would you cycle without being in a loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a section devoted to using `cycle` outside of loops on [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle):

> In some cases you might want to refer to the next value of a cycle from outside of a loop. To do this, just give the {% cycle %} tag a name, using "as", like this:
>
> ```
> {% cycle 'row1' 'row2' as rowcolors %}
> ```
>
> From then on, you can insert the current value of the cycle wherever you'd like in your template by referencing the cycle name as a context variable. If you want to move the cycle onto the next value, you use the cycle tag again, using the name of the variable. So, the following template:
>
> ```
> <tr>
>     <td class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' as rowcolors %}">...</td>
>     <td class="{{ rowcolors }}">...</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>     <td class="{% cycle rowcolors %}">...</td>
>     <td class="{{ rowcolors }}">...</td>
> </tr>
> ```
>
> would output:
>
> ```
> <tr>
>     <td class="row1">...</td>
>     <td class="row1">...</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>     <td class="row2">...</td>
>     <td class="row2">...</td>
> </tr>
> ```

So in your case, you'd just declare it once and then call `{% cycle name %}` on every row.